# Faster way of finding count of a category over a window function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a categorical column (well a discrete value column) and i would like to count the number of rows with each category over a centered sliding window function. I am using python with pandas as numpy to do this. I have something that works but it is slow and not so elegant.

I was wondering if there was a faster or easier way of doing this. I am running it over around 10,000 rows now and it takes around 20 seconds, which is ok but id like to run it over several 100,000 rows and up to 1,000,000 rows.

my code so far is as follows:

```
counted = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df[discrete_column].unique():
    counts = df[discrete_column].rolling(window_size, 0, True).apply(lambda x:np.where(x==i, 1,0).sum())
    counted[i]=counts
```

Comment: Can you provide a (small) example of input/output?

Answer (score 0):

input would be like this (index, column)

| index | discrete_column |
| --- | --- |
| 58702 | 65030 |
| 58703 | 65030 |
| 58704 | 65030 |
| 58705 | 65030 |
| 58706 | 65030 |
| 58707 | 30000 |
| 58708 | 30000 |
| 58709 | 30000 |
| 58710 | 30000 |

Output (this is just a snippet) and i used a window size of 20

| index | 65030 | 30000 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 58703 | 0.684211 | 0.315789 |
| 58704 | 0.650000 | 0.350000 |
| 58705 | 0.600000 | 0.400000 |
| 58706 | 0.550000 | 0.450000 |
| 58707 | 0.500000 | 0.500000 |
| 58708 | 0.450000 | 0.550000 |

each category from the input becomes a column and the values in the output are the proportions (renormalized to 1 across the row) of each category in that window size.